# How can I insert MySql Foreign Key data into another table using Insert statement?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert, statements

Im just having trouble adding foreign key data between multiple tables in MySql, The tables are already created with the FK constraints in place. E.g. Ive created the following table:

```
$tbl_transactions = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS transactions (
          transaction_id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
          datetime DATETIME DEFAULT NOW(),
          device_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
          quantity INT(11) NOT NULL,
          type_id INTEGER,
          ticket_id INTEGER,
          region_id INTEGER,
          user_id INTEGER,
          FOREIGN KEY (device_id) REFERENCES stock(device_id),
          FOREIGN KEY (type_id) REFERENCES transaction_type(type_id),
          FOREIGN KEY (ticket_id) REFERENCES tickets(ticket_id),
          FOREIGN KEY (region_id) REFERENCES regions(region_id),
          FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user_accounts(user_id)
         )";
```

Ive also already created the tables: stock, transactions_type, tickets, regions and user_accounts and just need to add data into the above transactions table that specifically references the primary keys of the 5 foreign key tables.

I know the sql statement will start as follows:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO transactions (datetime, device_id, quantity, type_id, ticket_id, region_id, user_id)
        VALUES...
```

Then im stuck, online examples seem to only discuss creating the tables rather than adding data into the tables.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Well you first need to add the data into the 5 tables and then use the IDs to finally add the data into the transactions table, otherwise you would get an error that a foreign key constraint fails

Comment: @Nan Sorry I forgot to mention, the 5 tables already have data, I just need to know the code that would add them, in a high level view

Comment: ok well your pretty much there: 'INSERT INTO transactions (datetime, device_id, quantity, type_id, ticket_id, region_id, user_id)
        VALUES (date_time_value, device_id_value, quantity_value, type_id_value, ticket_id_value, region_id_value, user_id_value)